# How do display alert message only once using jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, modal-dialog

I want to display alert message only once. How?
For example: If I open the Internet Explore www.stackoverflow.com, "the dialog box must appear on that time only".  If I click any other link or select something in the menu bar in the same page it's no need to appear the alert message again.

where i change my code?

```
$(function() {
$( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
            height: 200,
            width: 320,
            modal: true
        });
    });
```

html page

```
<pre><div id="dialog-modal" title="School Holiday" style="background-color:#00F"><p style="color:#FFF; font-size:16px; text-align: center;">The ART will be closed on Friday.</p></div><pre>
```

Comment: I'm assuming that you mean only once, even if they refresh the page?

Comment: @abi: you said you're using a "header page"; are you using a server side technology e.g. PHP?

Comment: I call this code in "home page". Now its display only once.  Any way thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this may be to set a cookie to indicate if the dialog has been previously shown.

```
if (!(document.cookie == "shown"))
{
    $( "#dialog-modal" ).dialog({
                height: 200,
                width: 320,
                modal: true
                        });
    document.cookie = "shown";
}
```

Note: I'm using a cookie as an example here. In reality, you'd want to use something more advanced like server-sided conditional HTML output (from a database) or using local storage.   Also, this allows you to use cookies with your website, and saves your client from wasting bandwith sending the cookie every request.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your prompt response. It's not working. i call this code in my header page, so its appear in all page. pls help me to solve this problem.  I am new for this post...

Comment: If you're using PHP and it is already setting cookies, then please use something *other* than cookies - cookies was a simple example for the implementation.

Comment: This message is appear in the home page.  After login the session will start. I don't know how to use cookie? pls give some idea.

Comment: As stated above, use an alternative storage method, such as [HTML5 local storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/). In simple terms, HTML5 local storage is a key-value store: to retrieve values: `var foo = localStorage["bar"];` and to set: `localStorage["bar"] = foo;`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking here. [I created a working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/tankchintan/uvfAx/) and as soon as the page loads you can see the alert/dialog box.

Can you tell us more about your question?

Comment: The alert message was display in all pages. I need to display the alert message only once.  for ex: If i open the www.google.com on that time "alert message" display. After that no need to display, until i close the window.